# Flutter : fetch image from picture Directory

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working with saved image from Url with [Gallery Saver](https://pub.dev/packages/gallery_saver). Everything it's oke , i can insert image from URL, but i don't know how to fetch image from picture Directory .

It's different about `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` or `getExternalStorageDirectory()` ?

I want to display the image that was just saved.

Any solution ?

#### Save image Code :

```
void _testSaveImage() async {
    String path = "${Urls.BASE_API_IMAGE}/berita/${widget.gambarBerita}";
    GallerySaver.saveImage(path).then((bool success) {
      print('Success add image $path');
    }).catchError((onError) {
      print('Error add image $path');
    });
  }
```

#### Location Image saved

[image: Image Location]

Comment: What exactly do you want? Fetch the image you just saved? Fetch any other Image or display the image you saved?

Comment: Ya, i want fetch image i have saved.
Because i want when user Offline, user still can see the image, i must download the image and fetch that. Any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then just return the `path` you have and use a `Image.file()` widget to display it, lets say you have a `Column()`:

```dart
Column(children: <Widget>[
  [...]
  Text('Here is my image:'),
  if (path.isNotEmpty && path != null)
    SizedBox(
      height: 200,
      width: 200,
      child: Image.file(File(path),
    ),
  Text('Caption of the image'),
  [...]
),
```

Docs for Image class [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

Load local saved images using path and use it

```
var file = new File('path');
Image.file(file )
```